# Sharepoint 2010 List Lookup values in ODATA

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, lookup-column, odata

It's a common case that you use lookups in your list.

When using ODATA, Is it possible to include the actual value of the lookup instead of the (other) SharePoint list item ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the lookup column.

```
https://***/sites/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/List?$select=Title,LookupColumn/OtherColumn&$expand=LookupColumn
```

In this example my list has a column called *LookupColumn* that looks up a value in another list. This other list has a column called *OtherColumn*. By expanding *LookupColumn* in your query you can access the value of *OtherColumn*.

Reference:

[Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx)

Comment: does this work for SharePoint 2010?
I always get a HTTP 400, so a bad request...

Comment: Yes, it should work. Maybe you can provide a bit more information, list schemas, the query you are using, etc.. Maybe we can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: sure, sorry:

http://***/sites/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ProjectStatusReports?$select=*,ProjectId/Project%20ID&$expand=ProjectId

Comment: Try it without %20. Spaces are automatically stripped from the column name when you query their data via ListData.svc. 'http://***/sites/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ProjectStatusReports?$select=*,ProjectId/Pr‌​ojectID&$expand=ProjectId'

Comment: If I can't see what the lookup column is (through the SP list settings interface) is it somehow possible to figure out with the help of the REST API?
I just got told that the list view is created through a workflow.
When I look at the xml I only see ProjectId (and some other columns) but in the view itself I see many other identifers like Project Name and ProjectID & Project:ID which I don't just don't see in the ODATA Query result

Comment: Not sure that I understand what you are saying. What is the problem now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42980/discussion-between-ahmed-h-and-daniel-stolzner).